# Determining True North from drone footage?

Tags: qgis-processing, metadata

I recently surveyed a site using a drone (not my own). I have composited together roughly 20 images to form an overall image of the site; however, this composited image contains no metadata pertaining to coordinate location. I am trying to find a way to determine True North based on the images I have put together. I'm guessing that there is a way to do this in QGIS; however, I'm not sure how without accurate metadata.

Comment: Can you match it (by eye) to a correctly aligned image from another source? Otherwise without metadata I doubt it.

Comment: If you only have an image, 1) then you need to find a similar image that has geo-referencing and attach your image to it and then solve your problem ... 2) if you have instrumental data for the area of your image at least 3-4 shafts , in this case, link the images to the instrumental data ...

Comment: Do you have a time stamp and can you measure the height of any objects on the site?

Comment: It seems that data on time and altitude are not available ...

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways of doing this.  The first requires a feature of known height and known time stamps for the images.  If you have these, you can calculate true north from the length and direction of the shadow of a feature of known height.  If you can't get the height of a feature, then you are into the realms of estimation, though it should be a close estimate if you are meticulous.

Alternatively, if you have some features whose coordinates you can accurately identify either from ground-truthing or from other data, then you can triangulate between them to derive a bearing for true north.

A third option is to overlay your images on Google, Bing or other aerial images (or even maps) and georeference the images accordingly.  This would probably be my preferred option as you're going to have to do that anyway to make any use of your merged image in a GIS.